# How to make html lists horizontal in css?

Tags: css, html, html-lists

I am trying to write a website with a toolbar at the top, the HTML for the toolbar is:

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home  </a></li>
  <li><p>|</p></li>
  <li><a href="aboutus.html">  About Us  </a></li>
  <li><p>|</p></li>
  <li><a href="contactus.html">  Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help you could give would be really apreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block` instead of `display: inline`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home  </a></li>
  <li> <p>|</p> </li>
  <li><a href="aboutus.html">  About Us  </a></li>
  <li><p>|</p></li>
  <li><a href="contactus.html">  Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is better option to do this with `Flexbox` and `:after` **pseudo-element**

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}
li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '|';
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these:

```
<li><p>|</p></li>
```

Because:

- Paragraph elements are blocks (and generate line breaks)
- Dividing characters are not paragraphs
- Dividing characters are not list items

Use CSS borders if you want a line between list items.

Comment: Css borders or place the character in pseudo elements.